# Symfony 5.1: Loading an own twig extension in a microkernel

Tags: symfony, twig-extension

switching to smyfony, we struggle with some basic starting issues.
We are transferring an existing project to symfony.
Due to that, f.eg. configurations etc are mandatory to be in php and dynimically - so far no problem.

but: How can i load an own twig function (extension) in the microkernel ?

kernel.php

```php
protected function configureContainer(ContainerConfigurator $container) {

  $container->extension("twig", array(
            "paths" => array(__DIR__ . "/../resources/views"),
            "auto_reload" => true,
            "cache" => false,
        ));

}
```

Twig is working fine and makes no problems ... undtil we need our own functions.

The (TEST !) twig function:

```php
namespace App\Kernel\TwigExtensions;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class TwigTest extends AbstractExtension {
    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new TwigFunction("test", array($this, function() { return "ABC"; })),
        );
    }
}
```

using the following source within "configureContainer" has no effect:

```php
$container->services()
                ->load("App\\Kernel\\TwigExtensions\\", sprintf("%s/Kernel/TwigExtensions/TwigTest.php", __DIR__))
                ->tag('twig.extension')
```

Any ideas for my next step ? Thanks !

Comment: You have registered the extensions with the container but not with twig itself, that's normally done by calling [`addExtension`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension). You can see how it's done in a [compiler pass](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/559ebe35fee2ebda9b09aa586f13e8b8207c3ec6/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TwigEnvironmentPass.php#L23).

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help. `addExtension` seems to be the point. But unfortunatly there is no `getDefinition('twig')` in the `configureContainer` fct in the kernel.php. i also cannot address twig as variable to add the extension directly, but i need to init the extensions there.

Comment: No, there's not, you have a `ContainerConfigurator` in there, not a `ContainerBuilder`, but you can create your own compiler pass and replicate what framework does.